# Code Upgrade tool error

Tags: version, upgrade, kentico

We are trying to upgrade the site from Kentico 8.2 To Kentico 9. In this there is lot of custom code.

We are using Code Upgrade tool as mentioned in the documentation to upgrade the code: Please check this
[image]

It will be really helpful if you could help us in this.

Comment: Could you please doublecheck your path is corrent? Can you run command with verbose param so we can see (maybe) more detailed console output?

Answer (score 0):

The error being referenced, `the path's format is not supported` can typically be resolved by copying and pasting the actual path from file explorer AND wrapping it in double quotes.  If your `WebsiteFolder` and/or the .sln file have spaces in them, it will error out unless wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Hi ,I am copying and pasting actual path from file explorer but it is not working...also  i wrapped path in double quotes also still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the file structure of your project? Have you changed the name or location of the CMS folder? What I would try is to install clean K8.2 installation, hotfix it to the same version you have and copy the "CMS" folder from your project to the clean install and see if it makes a difference.